# How to show all things in one single statement

Tags: mysql

Show all of the J,K, and L stock bin locations that have 
reorder levels at 5 or less.

```
 select BinLocation, ReorderLevel 
 from [Warehouse].[StockItemHoldings] 
 where BinLocation like '%J%' or BinLocation like '%K%' or BinLocation like '%L%' 
and ReorderLevel <= '5'
```

It is currently showing results with reoder levels that are higher than 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youn should enclose the or condition between ()

```
select BinLocation, ReorderLevel 
from [Warehouse].[StockItemHoldings] 
where (BinLocation like '%J%' or BinLocation like '%K%' or BinLocation like '%L%' ) 
and ReorderLevel <= '5'
```